# How to permanantly stop JavaFX code from being highlighted as an error within eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have recently started using JavaFX within eclipse, and am wondering how I can configure eclipse in a way that means I do not have to add a build path to each individual project I create to get Eclipse and JavaFX to correctly highlight errors in my code and unhighlight code that is error-free.

- **These are the resources I have used so far:**

guide to installing JavaFX:
https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

guide to correct error highlighting on a project by project basis:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYb78_TNG74

Comment: Why don't you just use the official documentation instead? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/